# PIL: DLL load failed: specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've been beginning to work with images in Python and I wanted to start using PIL (Pillow). To install it, I ran `pip install Pillow`. When installing, PIL was not previously installed. I also tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, as well as using `pip3 install Pillow`.

When I run it in Python, my first line is:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 56, in <module>
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I checked the directory, and the file _imaging.cp36-win_amd64.pyd is present under the PIL folder.

Why is this happening if the needed DLL is there? How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you rename _\_imaging.cp36-win\_amd64.pyd_ to _\_imaging.pyd_?

Comment: I tried doing that, and it didn't help. I received the same error as before.

Comment: What's the _Win_ version that you're running on (I have a suspicion related to architecture mismatch)?

Comment: Win as in Windows? I am running 10.0.14393

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing PIL, more specifically Image from PIL, isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43267754/importing-pil-more-specifically-image-from-pil-isnt-working)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had this problem as well with Python 3.6. I just avoided the problem by uninstalling pillow (4.1.0) and then installing an older version of pillow (4.0.0).  It seems to run okay with the older version.

Comment: uninstalling 4.1.0 and doing pip install Pillow==4.0.0 worked for me python 3.6.0, windows 10

Comment: You solved my day! Worked for me in Win10 and python 3.6.0

Comment: Same! It's not normal that going from 4.0.0 to 4.1 breaks everything. There should be some kind of test or whatever to check this.

Comment: Pillow 4.1.1 is now out which you can use for both Python 3.6.0 and 3.6.1. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43723021/724176

Comment: I have the same problem now with python 3.6.3 and pillow 4.2.1 and 4.3.0. Downgrading to 4.1.1 solves the problem.

Answer (score 28):

As in Sean's answer, I had to uninstall (I'm using Anaconda Python 3.6, BTW) with

```
conda uninstall pillow
```

I tried it with PIL, but there was no such package. Uninstalling pillow also meant uninstalling packages that depend on it, in my case "anaconda-navigator" and "scikit-image". After I reinstalled Pillow 4.0.0 with

```
 conda install pillow=4.0.0
```

and tested it with

```
python -c "from PIL import Image"
```

which, if successful, you don't see an error message, I reinstalled the packages that were uninstalled along with Pillow 4.1.0.

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
conda install scikit-image
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Using Windows 10 and Python 3.5

Comment: On Win10 with Python 3.5 with conda environment. I desinstalled pillow with conda, reinstalled pillow with pip. And then reinstalled scikit-image with pip and anaconda-navigator with conda (without dependencies install '--no-deps').

Comment: Does not work
 PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pillow==4.0.0

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Anaconda, try

`conda uninstall pillow`  and then `pip install pillow`

Came across this issue while working on Caffe2 on Windows 10 (Anaconda 4.5) and this worked for me. Here's the [github post](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945) on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is also fixed by upgrading Python to 3.6.1, per [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2479#issuecomment-292252147).

> The difference is that Pillow 4.1.0 was built with Python 3.6.1 while Pillow 4.0.0 was built with Python 3.6.0.
>
> Apparently `PYTHON36.DLL` from Python 3.6.0 is missing functions (`PySlice_AdjustIndices` and `PySlice_Unpack`) that are used when building with Python 3.6.1.
>
> The solution is to upgrade to Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Pillow 4.1.1 is now out which you can use for both Python 3.6.0 and 3.6.1. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43723021/724176

Comment: Running Python 3.6.4/Win64 `conda install pillow=4.1.1` finally did the trick. No prior uninstall required.

Answer (score 4):

There's a problem in Python itself which means binary wheels build using Python 3.6.1 (like Pillow 4.1.0) won't install on Python 3.6.0.

This has affected a number of Python libraries.

However, there's the new Pillow 4.1.1 release works around this, so you can now update to Pillow 4.1.1 and use it with both Python 3.6.0 and 3.6.1.

More info:

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2479
- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-March/147707.html
- https://bugs.python.org/issue29943

Answer (score 2):

for new people 2022
i solved it
you can look at this
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

if PIL don't want to  uninstall delete or cut it to another folder

I edits that for people ,who don't read comments:

it depend on your python version , if your python 3.11 ,you can just install pillow >=9.3 if your python version 3.9 ,you can install pillow >=8.3.2 but you can not install pillow 8.3.1 , you need to uninstall it first or move it to another directory

Comment: what exactly has to be done there?

Comment: this answer adds no value. it merely points to official docs that describe installation.

Comment: The page says "Pillow >= 2.1.0 no longer supports `import _imaging`. Please use `from PIL.Image import core as _imaging` instead. Perhaps that's what's required.

Comment: it depend on your python version , if your python 3.11 ,you can just install pillow >=9.3 if your python version 3.9 ,you can install pillow >=8.3.2 but you can not install pillow 8.3.1 , you need to uninstall it first or move it to another directory

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using win10 and py 3.6.
Simply uninstall Pillow 4.1.0 
pip3 uninstall Pillow
Then install Pillow 4.0.0
pip3 install Pillow==4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with anaconda 5.0.1, using it with caffe on windows 10. i just did

`conda install PIL`

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some issue is there with tensorflow 1.12.0 +Python 3.6.0 + win10

Working fine with conda tensorflow.

below steps worked for me for pip tensorflow.

uninstall tensorflow
replace your python version with 3.6.1
install latest version of tensorflow(1.13.0)

For installing Tensorflow follow below link:-
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user and do not have Microsoft Visual C++ the error occurs. I got the same error and resolved this by installing the Microsoft Visual C++. Link for downloading can be found here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Python 3.9.12.
I uninstalled the pre-installed Pillow version 9.0.1 and simply reinstalled the latest version 9.5.0

```
$ pip3 uninstall pillow

Found existing installation: pillow 9.0.1
Uninstalling pillow-9.0.1:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\sjitb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pil\*
    c:\users\sjitb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pillow-9.0.1-py3.9.egg-info
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pillow-9.0.1
```

```
$ pip install pillow

Collecting pillow
  Downloading Pillow-9.5.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.5 MB 2.2 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pillow
Successfully installed pillow-9.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For people in 2023,
for Python 3.10.13, pillow version 10.0.1 worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

First uninstall existing version

```
pip uninstall pillow
```

Then try installing

```
pip install pillow==4.0.0
```

Comment: What is the point to post same answer as the accepted one after 3.5 years? (and some other include this info as well)