# python pillow DLL load failed

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm using Python 3.6.4 with pillow 5.0.0, through Anaconda.

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Anaconda2\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Probably the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43264773/1568919). But that was 10 months ago and the answer says it was fixed with Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Have You tried downgrading the Pillow as it was noted in the question You've just linked?

Comment: @Kamiccolo, yes, that seems to work. But downgrading pillow to 4.0.0 means other packages especially numpy and matplotlib need to be downgraded, which is not good for me

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Anaconda distribution, try removing it with Conda:

```
conda uninstall pillow
```

and installing it using pip:

```
pip install pillow
```

You can test that it's working:

```
python -c "from PIL import Image"
```