# DLL error while importing the Python Imaging Library

Tags: python

I'm having troubles using scikit-image module skimage :

```
from skimage import io

img = io.imread('mire.jpg', as_grey=True)
io.imshow(img)
```

Here's the error message I get :

```
runfile('C:/Users/Niz/Documents/MIX/M1/S2/TRAITEMENT DE DONNEES D\'IMAGES/TP 01/TP_image_convolution/test skimage.py', wdir='C:/Users/Niz/Documents/MIX/M1/S2/TRAITEMENT DE DONNEES D\'IMAGES/TP 01/TP_image_convolution')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-514bc33b76c2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Niz/Documents/MIX/M1/S2/TRAITEMENT DE DONNEES D\'IMAGES/TP 01/TP_image_convolution/test skimage.py', wdir='C:/Users/Niz/Documents/MIX/M1/S2/TRAITEMENT DE DONNEES D\'IMAGES/TP 01/TP_image_convolution')

  File "C:\Users\Niz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Niz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Niz/Documents/MIX/M1/S2/TRAITEMENT DE DONNEES D'IMAGES/TP 01/TP_image_convolution/test skimage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from skimage import io

  File "C:\Users\Niz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manage_plugins import *

  File "C:\Users\Niz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .collection import imread_collection_wrapper

  File "C:\Users\Niz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\collection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PIL import Image

  File "C:\Users\Niz\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

I'm running python 3.6.4 on windows 10 using anaconda Spyder, and I installed scikit-image using :

```
conda install scikit-image
```

I've looked over the threads and tried installing **numpy-mkl** and some **visual c++ libraries** but I still get the same error message.

Sorry for bad english, french speaker here! Thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to this thread : [PIL: DLL load failed: specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264773/pil-dll-load-failed-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)

It seems running pillow on version 4.0.0 fixed my issue :

```
conda uninstall pillow
pip install pillow==4.0.0
```

Then install scikit-image again

```
conda install scikit-image
```