# DLL load failed : Python modules accessible through Spyder but import fail in cmd

Tags: import, module, spyder, python-3.7

I have seen many more or less related questions on this topic, but none helped me finding a way to solve my problem.
I'm not very familiar with Windows environment, deep apologies if my question sounds obvious to some extent.

Setup:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.7.0 (installed through latest Anaconda release)
- Spyder 3.3.1

Im running a Python, that involves several modules import. I came across some module issues. For example:

```
from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
```

Works smooth in Spyder, but gives (error message in french but I guess you got the point):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\my_user_name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 64, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

If executed in Powershell or cmd.

**What I tried:**

- Appending Anaconda's install path to my path variable before I open Powershell:

  ```
  $Env:path += ";C:\Users\my_user_name\Anaconda3;C:\Users\my_user_name\Anaconda3\Scripts"
  ```
- Checking that sys.path is the same in Powershell and Spyder. For both, it looks like:

  ```
   ['',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
    'C:\\Users\\my_user_name\\.ipython']
  ```

What else could explain that my import fails outside of Spyder ?

Comment: By any chance, where is this dll located?

Comment: I did a search on _imaging and found two relevant hits: one in Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/PIL and one in Anaconda3\pkgs\pillow-5.2.0-py37h08bbbbd_0\Lib\site-packages\PIL

Comment: `Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/PIL` is not in your path, and not the other either. No idea what sort of magic Spyder or Anaconda does. I prefer to run things in a terminal as-is.. So I'm of no use here sadly.

Comment: It seems you're using Powershell, try to run cmd instead and see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, cmd gives exactly the same thing.

Comment: I've seen problems like this before, and had them myself. The `PATH` variable is unrelated to python import errors. Would you be able to give us a list of every file inside the `\site-packages\PIL` including files in subfolders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I could not find a clean way out, so let me just share my experience in case someone finds it helpful ...

The DLL failure with PIL related libs seems to be a known issue. See further explanations:

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945
- [PIL: DLL load failed: specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264773/pil-dll-load-failed-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)

**How I solved my issue:**

- Cleanly uninstalled anything related to Python on my laptop. Both Anaconda, isolated Python installs, Spyder ...
- Re-installed the latest Anaconda. It happens to come with Python 3.7.1 instead of 3.7.0
- Re-did my PIP installs of everything. Note I had to append *Anaconda\Library\bin* to my Windows path for PIP to work completely, which I don't recall having done with my previous installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when importing scipy related modules and after struggling for days, this solution had worked for me:

**How I solved my issue:**

- Launch the Spyder editor.
- Tools -> Current user environment variables
- Double click "Path"
- Edit these paths based on your installation:

`X:ProgramDataAnaconda3` --> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3

`X:ProgramDataAnaconda3Scripts` --> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts

`X:ProgramDataAnaconda3Librarybin` --> C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Paths might differ based on your installation folder.