# Can run script from pycharm, but not from Terminal. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library, python-import

```
import PIL.ImageGrab

im = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()
```

Works in Pycharm, does not form command line. Tried many things, can be seen below, not sure what else to change.

```
C:\Users\a.b>C:\Users\a.b\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\a.b\PycharmProjects\emlekezteto\screenshot.py

C:\Users\a.b>C:\Users\a.b\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\a.b\PycharmProjects\emlekezteto\screenshot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\a.b\PycharmProjects\emlekezteto\screenshot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PIL.ImageGrab
  File "C:\Users\a.b\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import Image
  File "C:\Users\a.b\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 90, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

## Things I checked:

### 1. Pycharm interpreter is same. In Pycharm, and command line:

```
C:\Users\a.b\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
```

### 2. Even when working directory is the same, i.e. putting below thing in code, still same issue. By default this is working directory in Pycharm when running form there.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\a.b\PycharmProjects\emlekezteto')
```

### 3. The sys.path was different, for Pycharm:

```
['C:\\Users\\a.b\\PycharmProjects\\emlekezteto', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\PycharmProjects\\emlekezteto', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\PycharmProjects\\emlekezteto', 'C:/Users/a.b/PycharmProjects/emlekezteto']
```

in cmd:

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Even when I extend sys.path with all the Pycharm sys.path hardcoded in code, it still gives the same error.

```
 import os
    print (os.getcwd())
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\a.b\PycharmProjects\emlekezteto')
    print (os.getcwd())

    import sys; print(sys.path)

sys.path.extend(['C:\\Users\\a.b\\PycharmProjects\\emlekezteto', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\PycharmProjects\\emlekezteto', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\third_party\\thriftpy', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\a.b\\PycharmProjects\\emlekezteto', 'C:/Users/a.b/PycharmProjects/emlekezteto'])

    print (sys.path)
    import PIL.ImageGrab
    im = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
    im.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the exact versions of what you have installed: PyCharm, python, anaconda, PIL, etc. I posted a couple of links below, they suggest you might have a version mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out if you haven't seen them, they seem similar/relevant:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945

[PIL: DLL load failed: specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264773/pil-dll-load-failed-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)

Comment: thank you, followed github link: had to delete pillow manually from site_packages folder of anaconda, then used pip install to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem really annoyed me for a while.
I runned my script normally in Pycharm. But it reported this error when I runned it in terminal. The 2 packages which I imported that caused this error are:

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp 
from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum
```

I tried all solutions online, but none of them worked. Finally I solved it by importing pandas before importing the above packages:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Them I can run the script normally in terminal. This works for me.